# "Run all code blocks above this point" in org-babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I know you can use `org-babel-execute-src-block` (`C-c C-c`) to execute individual code blocks, but is there something akin to "Run all chunks above" that RStudio has for Rmarkdown files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily run **all** code blocks via `C-c C-v C-b`, or all blocks in a subtree. I don't think **above this point** is implemented.

It would be fairly easy write a custom function that takes all text below the point, hides it, executes all code blocks, and then restores the text. I would do that rather than taking all text above the point and executing it in a temporary buffer, because some code blocks may use the buffer-name or file-name so it should not be changed.

Comment: **Note**: Because of `<< noweb >>` remote code inclusion, it may be difficult to know that blocks above don't depend on blocks below.